# Multi-threaded UDP server with Python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, udp

I want to create a simple video streaming (actually, image streaming) server that can manage different protocols (TCP Push/Pull, UDP Push/Pull/Multicast).

I managed to get TCP Push/Pull working with the `SocketServer.TCPServer` class and `ThreadinMixIn` for processing each connected client in a different thread.

But now that I'm working on the UDP protocol, I just realized that ThreadinMixIn creates a thread per call of `handle()` per client query (as there's nothing such as a "connection" in UDP).

The problem is I need to process a sequence of queries by the same client, for all the clients. How could I manage that ?

The only way I see I could handle that is to have a list of (client adresses, processing thread) and send each query to the matching thread (or create a new one if the client haven't sent any thread yet). Is there an easier way to do that ?

Thanks !

P.S : I can't use any external or too "high-level" library for this as it's a school subject meant to understand how sockets work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).  This will remove the need to do any thread dispatch from your application.  You still have to match up packets to a particular session in order to handle them, but this isn't difficult (use a port per client and dispatch based on the port, or require packets in a session to always come from the same address and use the peer address, or  use one of the existing protocols that solves this problem such as SIP).

Comment: I forgot to say that I can't use any external (or too high-level) libraries, like Twisted for instance;

But it seems like I *must* manage "sessions" in UDP myself (unlike TCP).

Comment: Python itself is effectively a high-level library, so it doesn't make sense that you can use Python but not Twisted.  And yes, UDP itself has no concept of a session.

Comment: What I mean by "high-level" is to setup a server without coding the queries handling part yourself.

Anyway, I think I'll just go on with this 'session' system (with a FIFO queue per address, where queries are stored). Thank you !